# Rewrite function , when should I use local/mage and when shouldI use the rewrite by a module

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

I'm working on **Magento 1.9**

I can see I have 2 options to rewrite a mage file .
First, I just copy the file with the same path in `local/mage/....`
Second, I use a module and rewrite my method using `etc/config.xml`

Why there is 2 options ? 
When should I use the first one , and when should I use the second one ?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2):

Briefly :

- I use `override` if this is a Magento Core Bug correction. I copy/paste the file in the local pool and just add a comment in top of the file to explain the bug and his correction (most of times there is a link to a stackoverflow question ...)
- I use `rewrite` if I have to add or modify a feature (and when this is not possible to do this with an event/observer)

Answer (score 1):

You should do the difference between `override` and `rewrite`

`rewrite` = is when you rewrite: controllers, models, blocks, via **xml**

`override` = is when you copy the file from `app/code/core` to `app/code/local`

All rewrites are overrides, but not all overrides are rewrites, **for exemple** tha `abstract` classes, we can't `rewrite` them but, we can `override`.

More informations in [benmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105798/difference-between-override-and-rewrite-in-magento) explanation.