# how to override community module in local magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working on updating 3rd party module with local module so i have added all updated files same in local as community module like 
community module:   to local 
and added updated files.But 50% people saying to write config for this local module to overide.And others saying just copy & paste updated code in local
so help me regards

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the right place for a community extension is the community pool.

Then, as for the question https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/248000/50208,
I would copy/paste in the local pool only if this is a bug correction. If you have to add a feature, create your own extension (that extends the community extension one) and use rewrite (if the event/observer way is not possible).

Answer (score 0):

You can copy and paste the code to your local folder, I think this way is easier and more manageable. Just make sure to change the code pool under app/etc/modulename.xml!

Here's an example of modulename.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Modulename>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <edition>community</edition>
        </Namespace_Modulename>
    </modules>
</config>
```

See how codepool is local, you will need to change it from community to local.